# Assignment problem cost matrix reconstruction justification

Tags: operations-research, extremal-combinatorics

I have asked questions numerically on this topic, but here is a theoretical question that i want to ask, if the answer is affirmative, then only can i proceed with my problem. I have an assignment problem whose solution I have, i.e. I know the job assignments been done, and I know the minimum cost of the entire problem. My question is can I get the cost matrix from these two information, or can i get some approximation of the cost matrix. Please refer to question [Finding integer solutions to a multivariable equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3650045/finding-integer-solutions-to-a-multivariable-equation/3651603#3651603).

Answer (score 0):

No. Consider a 2x2 assignment problem (two workers, two jobs), and let $C$ be the 2x2 cost matrix. Assume that the optimal solution assigns worker 1 to job 1 and worker 2 to job 2, at total cost $z$. That tells you the following two things:\begin{align*}
C_{11}+C_{22} & =z\\
C_{11}+C_{22} & \le C_{12}+C_{21}.
\end{align*} Conversely, that information is sufficient to dictate the solution you have. Even if you assume $C\ge 0$, you have an uncountably infinite number of solutions to that system, all of which are consistent with what you know.